# Flutter ios pod install changes deployment target

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-ios

So i’m trying to build my Flutter application for ios and my minimum deployment target is ios 11  (because of some other plugins I use)

But pod install sets the target of DKPhotoGallery pods to ios 9 which fails the build,
I can change it on Xcode manually to ios 11 and then I can build it successfully,

but since flutter run calls 'pod install' it changes it back to ios 9 and it fails, how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the end of pod file

Please change the required IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

```
post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
        t.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes, this worked but i set it to '11.0' not '9.0' thank you

Comment: Okay, I'll edit and mention to change the version so that one changes the version

Answer (score 0):

You can change the platform to `platform :ios, '11'` in your `Podfile`, it's at the first line of your Podfile

Comment: use `pod cache clean --all` and after that install it again

Comment: if it doesn't work deintegrate your pod with `pod deintegrate` and after that install it again

Comment: try all but not work! @Hamed